# Why is there id_supplier in the product table and a product_supplier table?

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

In Prestashop 1.7, why is there an `id_supplier` field in the `product` table and a `product_supplier` table? Isn't it redundant?

Answer (score 0):

`product_supplier`table was added in PS 1.5
to handle multi-suppliers capability for products
so you should always rely on `ProductSupplier` class
for Supplier related operations.

`id_supplier` in `product` table is used to store
the default supplier, if selected.